# How to handle child elements having same names but under different parent nodes in HttpRequest?

Tags: html, forms, httprequest

I have child elements with same names but they are under different parent nodes having different names themselves in HTML form. When I submit this form, how will I able to access these child attribute values from HttpRequest object at server side?

Clarification:

Actually I have many cloned divs which are having multiple input fields. Divs have different names but IDs of input fields are same across these divs. I was thinking if I can somehow differentiate child names using their parent div ids at server side, it would have been lot easier. Otherwise, I will have to add additional javascript code to rename these child nodes so they will differ.

Answer (score 1):

If you send form using HTTP request, only named elements values are sent (not HTML DOM) and latter overwrites earlier. So use different names.

You may use something like random name mangler. If you have form like this

```
<form id="test">
  <input name="foo"/>
  <input name="bar"/>
  <input name="foo"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

you can add random suffix to every variable just before the form is send

```
<script>
  var mangled = false;
  document.getElementById("test").onsubmit = function(e) {
    // add suffix on first submit
    if(!mangled) for(var i=0; i<this.length; ++i) {
      this[i].name+= "_"+Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
    }
    mangled = true;
    e.preventDefault(); // disable default submit

    // send form using XHR
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","yourserver",true);
    xhr.send(new FormData(this)); // send the form data to the server
  }
</script>
```

The server will receive something like this:

```
foo_88428=a&bar_69516=b&foo_84602=c
```

On the server you may drop the `_[number]` suffix of each variable and handle duplicities the way you like.

The string above is *raw post data* (google it for your server language support). Technically you can handle the data if some name is inserted twice, like

```
foo=a&bar=b&foo=c
```

but I wouldn't recommend it since it is [race hazard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_hazard) antipattern.

Comment: So are there any alternatives to HTTP request if I have to get HTML DOM structure at server side?

Comment: Do you want to send HTML DOM or form values to the server? Please describe some details about your problem and why you can't use different names.

Comment: Actually I have many cloned divs which are having multiple input fields. Divs have different names but IDs of input fields are same across these divs. I was thinking if I can somehow differentiate child names using their parent div ids at server side, it would have been lot easier. Otherwise, I will have to add additional javascript code to rename these child nodes so they will differ.

Comment: Could you add this clarification to your question? Others may have better ideas. Or you can just alter my code: instead random suffix use this line: `this[i].name+= "_"+this[i].parentNode.id`

Comment: I have added the clarification to the question as per you requested. I am currently prefixing all the child node names with their parent ids. But I was looking for a better way, like, I mean in DOM we already know they are different because they are under different parents, but we are not able to maintain that segregation in httprequest.

Comment: It is possible, but not advisable, see the added *raw post data* note at the end of my answer.